# Using l'Hôpital rule to find $\lim_{x\to-\infty} xe^x$

Tags: calculus, limits, exponential-function

I'm trying to solve this limit:

> $$\lim_{x\to-\infty} xe^x$$

I'm trying to solve this limit using the l'Hôpital rule. My question is: can I use this rule in the last limit below?

$\lim_{x\to-\infty} xe^x=\lim_{x\to-\infty} \frac{x}{e^{-x}}$

Note the numerator tends to $-\infty$, while the denominator tends to $\infty$, can I use the l'Hôpital rule in this case?

Thanks

Comment: Yes----------------

Comment: You can use it as long as the denominator is infinite regardless of the numerator (assuming the limit exists).

Comment: @brad which limit? numerator limit? or the limit itself?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to compute $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to -\infty}\frac{-x}{e^{-x}}$. Numerator and denominator tend to $\infty$, so you can use l'Hospital rule.

$$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to -\infty}\frac{-x}{e^{-x}}=\lim_{x \to -\infty}\frac{-1}{-e^{-x}}=\lim_{x \to -\infty}\frac{1}{e^{-x}}=0$$, so

$$\lim_{x \to -\infty}\frac{x}{e^{-x}}=-\lim_{x \to -\infty}\frac{-x}{e^{-x}}=0$$

Comment: This is right but you should probably say why `f(lim g(x)) = lim f(g(x))`, with `f(x) = -x` in this case.

Comment: @FrankConry I didn't understand why we have to use this fact in this solution.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Your concern is that the top and bottom seem to go to different infinities. Could you multiply in such a way as to get rid of that difference?

Comment: How is this a hint?  (There's no constant factor in this problem.)  And, in any event, constant factors *do* make a difference: $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{2x}{x} \ne \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x}{x}$

Comment: @anorton let me phrase it a bit differently

Comment: @anorton: Constant factors make a difference in the numerical result, but not in whether or not the limit is finite/zero/infinity.

Comment: @anorton You can pull arbitrary constant factors to the outside of a convergent limit.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try a substitution:

$$y=-x\implies \left(x\to -\infty\implies y\to\infty\right)$$

and your limit becomes

$$\lim_{x\to-\infty} xe^{x}=\lim_{y\to\infty}-ye^{-y}=-\lim_{y\to\infty}\frac y{e^y}$$

and you don't need to worry about signs anymore.